# Any EncryptionMode in FluentFTP?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, fluentftp

I need to apply encryption mode in FluentFTP's ftp.

The syntax "EncryptionMode" don't exist in .net 6.

```
var conn = new FtpClient();
conn.EncryptionMode = FtpEncryptionMode.Explicit;
```

[image]

How should I apply EncryptionMode in FluentFTP's ftp in .net6?

Thank you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

Config.EncryptionMode

https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP/wiki/FTP-Connection#how-do-i-connect-with-ssltls--how-do-i-use-ftps